# Music tag finder API .NET library

Tags: .net, api, mp3, last.fm, musicbrainz

I'm trying to build an application that can be used to automatically get music tag information from the web and rename my music library. I have been searching on google for any API available to help me out. So far, it seems like Discogs, Freedb, Last.fm, MusicBrainz, amazon and yahoo music are all good options for this. However, I am wondering if there is any .NET library that can be easily used to access any of the above libraries. Please help if you know any .DLL file that I can easily include to my C# project.

P.S: I have little knowledge with xml. It would help much if this API is a dll file as they are easy to work with than xml

Thanks in advance for your much appreciated help!

Answer (score 0):

Banshee project contains such features, and it may already have dlls for you to reference,

http://banshee.fm/download/development/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend http://code.google.com/p/lastfm-sharp/, i haven't used it for tags. I used it in combination with the direct api to download my lastFm data to the database.

http://code.google.com/p/lastfm-sharp/wiki/Examples
for examples including tags :)

Comment: It is exactly what I wanted. However, I am getting this error:The namespace name 'Lastfm' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) I have added lastfm-sharp.dll to the reference but still I get the same error. Also, I get a warning that the referenced assembly "lastfm-sharp, Version=0.1.10.39897, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ac974b34236b3339, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Web, which is not in the currently targeted framework ".

Comment: sorry for late answer, but have you added "using Lastfm.Services;"

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/7301dec4-4b96-444d-88bb-630125d080e4/

take a look at this guide, i think it will solve the system.web problem =) Have a small (fussy) memory of that i had the same problem